# C++ Reference Handle

Tags: c++

concerning code from Accelerated C++:

```
template <class T> class Ref_handle {
public:
Ref_handle(): refptr(new size_t(1)), p(0) { }
Ref_handle(T* t): refptr(new size_t(1)), p(t) { }
Ref_handle(const Ref_handle& h): refptr(h.refptr), p(h.p)
{
 ++*refptr;  //???
}
~Ref_handle();
private:
 T* p;
 size_t* refptr;
};
```

I understand the principle of handle, but I don't understand why compiler allows this kind op copy constructor. It copies pointers, but since it's pointing to a same size_t object, it's actually changing its value, although we "promised" with const that we won't change it.

Comment: The `const` is on `h`. You promised you wouldn't change `h`, not the current object.

Comment: I know, but with changing the current object, I'm also changing the value that h.refptr points to

Comment: @Bade That value isn't part of the object, only the pointer is. And you're not changing the current object either.

Comment: Oh, so the only thing I mustn't do is to change value of h.refptr, like: h.refptr = 0; ?

Comment: Yes. There are two separate `Ref_handle` objects: `*this` and `h`. There is also a third object, a `size_t`. In the copy constructor body, the `refptr` member of both `*this` and `h` point to the same `size_t` object in memory. `++*refptr` is changing neither `Ref_handle` object. It changes the `size_t` object.

Comment: Note that your code cannot function correctly: you'll have either a memory leak or a double-free, depending on how you implement the destructor. You need to create a new `size_t` object on the heap and copy the value of the `size_t` object pointed to by the original, like this: `Ref_handle(const Ref_handle& h): refptr(new size_t(h.refptr)), p(h.p) {}`